# When picture is uploaded it has a white background

Tags: php, html, css

Not sure if this is the right place to ask but I've got an image for my website and I removed the background of it on powerpoint, but when I upload it is a white background around it. Even if I set the background colour to something else, it'll have the colour I choose but also the white around it. No idea how to get rid of the white so would appreciate any guidance.

```css
img {
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://jg-ross.000webhostapp.com/pageUploads/logo.png" style="background-color:red; padding:20px;">
```

I'm wanting there to be no background whatsoever, when I load the image on powerpoint there is no white but once I've uploaded it to my website, the white is there.

In the images folder where it is stored it also a white box around the image, what causes this and can I get rid of it?

Here is how I upload it, the image is stored in an sql table:

```
<?php
    try {
    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT image_title, image FROM images WHERE id= 2 ');
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo "<img src='pageUploads/".$row['image']."'height='50px'";
    }
}catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

?>

```
<?php
require_once('../includes/config.php');
$target_dir = "../pageUploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

            //collect form data
        extract($_POST);

    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 2000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
        $upload =  basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

            try {

                //insert into database
                $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO images (image_title,image) VALUES (:image_title, :image)') ;
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':image_title' => $image_title,
                    ':image' => $upload

                ));

                //redirect to index page
                header('Location: images.php?action=added');
                exit;

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }



?>
```

Comment: The image has a white background instead of transparent one. The reason is probably in your upload mechanism but we are unable to tell you why without the code.

Comment: Just replace the white background of the image with a transparent one.

Comment: this is a question for https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Comment: The code shows how you query. But how did you deal with the uploading?

Comment: sorry, updated now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using powerpoint to export an image, powerpoint is not an image editor. PNGs can be saved with transparency conserved but you'll need to use something like Photoshop.

Take this image for example, say we want to remove the black borders and make them transparent:

[image]

Use magic eraser tool to delete borders

[image]
[image]

Next 'Save for web' and select "Transparency"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AS i read your question i go to know that you have edited image in POWERPOINT That might be the problem can you try editing the image in photoshop or online follow link bellow for whatever option is better for you?
(edit Online)

https://www.photopea.com/

(photoshop method)
You can simply use photoshop to remove the white background by going to this link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SV38L4c4JKY